# Using Postman to test OAuth Authentication Code Flow

Tags: postman, identityserver4

I'm trying to use Postman to test the Authentication Code Flow - but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I'm not sure if this is IS4 or a Postman issue.

I've created a new instance using the documentation from here:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/0_overview.html

Created a new Client:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "code",

                RedirectUris =
                {
                    "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
                },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,

                 ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("apisecret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedScopes = 
                { 
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1" 
                },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

Then using Postman trying to get an id token.

[image: POstman]

I then login with either bob/bob or alice/alice and when I click the Login button it just redirects back to the login screen.

I was expecting the access token to be retrieved.

I get the same issue when also testing against the demo instance (https://demo.identityserver.io/) using the SPA client.

If I use SoapUi it works.

Comment: What steps are you taking in Postman? I'm unfamiliar with whatever feature is displayed in the screenshot where you can just click 'Request Token'

Comment: This looks to be caused by by setting the SameSite attribute on the authorisation cookie to None. As Postman is using Chrome 66 this will reject any cookies that have this set to None.

If you don't set the SameSite attribute for Postman requests (i.e. via User Agent detection) then it should work.

This link gives more details on incompatible clients:
https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients